How to inject nonce from express.js node to angular 19?
According to docs:


Set the ngCspNonce attribute on the root application element as . Use this approach if you have access to server-side templating that can add the nonce both to the header and the index.html when constructing the response.
Provide the nonce using the CSP_NONCE injection token. Use this approach if you have access to the nonce at runtime and you want to be able to cache the index.html.


However with new engine AngularNodeAppEngine i have no clue what should i do to achive this.

In angular 19 can you try adding it to the providers array of serverConfig. This seems to generate the nonce when generating a build.
import { mergeApplicationConfig, ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideServerRendering } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { appConfig } from './app.config';
import { CSP_NONCE } from '@angular/core';

const serverConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideServerRendering(),
    {
      provide: CSP_NONCE,
      useValue: `default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'nonce-${Math.random()}'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-${Math.random()}';`,
    },
  ],
};

export const config = mergeApplicationConfig(appConfig, serverConfig);

Stackblitz Demo -> cd test -> npm i -> npm run build -> do a global search in dist folder for nonce

This will not work because the nonce value is placed in the CSP header, which is generated in Express.js. Therefore, regenerating this value at the Angular level is incorrect.
Moreover, consider that the CSP_NONCE token should contain only the generated nonce, not the entire CSP header value.
